# Pre fill and submit a form in in a view with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have this very simplified AangularJS app. It is working very well.

Now, I need to fill some fields and submit the form directly from the view, without user interaction.

Here's the Javascript code (once again, simplified and I removed many other elements)

```
    mainApp.controller("resultsController",FormController);
    function FormController($scope,APIService) {
        $scope.result ="";
        $scope.search = { keywords: "",
                          result:1,
                          term: "-1",
                          subject: "-1"};
        $scope.searchNow = function() {
            APIService.getTheResults($scope);
        } // $scope.searchNow

    }

    function getResults($http) {
        var results = {};
        url = "...";

        results.searchResults = function() {
            var lurl = url + "a=s";
            return $http( {method: "JSONP", url:lurl} );
        } // results.searchResults

        results.getTheResults = function(scope) {
            var lurl = url;
            $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url:lurl,
             data:jQuery.param(scope.search),
             headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
                .success(function(lresponse){
                    var theResponse;
                    theResponse = eval(lresponse);
                    scope.mydata = theResponse.data[0]
                })
                .error( function(data,status) {
                    scope.result = status;
                });
        } // results.getTheResults
        return results;
    } // function getResults($http)
```

And here is the HTML view:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="courseCatalog" ng-controller="resultsController">
  <!-- some head info -->
<body>
<form id="search_form" name="search_form" ng-submit="searchNow()">
 <!--
  form fields in here, for example:
 -->
  <input type="text" id="txtkeywords" name="keywords" ng-model="search.keywords">
  <input type="text" id="txtsubject" name="term" ng-model="search.subject">
  <input type="text" id="textterm" name="subject" ng-model="search.term">
  <input id="submit-button" name="submit-button" type="submit"
            value=" Search Now "/>
</form>

<!-- Here is the , I pre-populate some form fields -->
<div id='filter_holder' class='hidden_box'>
 <div class='hidden_box'>{{search.term='1|201601';}}</div>
 <div class='hidden_box'>{{search.subject='6|BIO';}}</div>
</div>
<!-- And here, I try to manually submit the form -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('submit-button').click();
  </script>
</body>
```

But I only get the page to reload with all the formfields in the url:

...url.../?txtterm=-1&txtsubject=-1&submit-button=+Search+Now+

I tried also submitting with document-form-submit but I get no results.

If I remove all the pre-fill/submit and manually fill and send the form I get the correct results.

Any idea on how to submit the form from the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try using form method post. So change your form tag to:

```
<form id="search_form" name="search_form" ng-submit="searchNow()" method="post">
```

As described in [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) chapter at w3schools, when using post method the data will not be shown in the url.

> "POST offers better security because the submitted data is not visible
>   in the page address."

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the method="post" to the form declaration, but the page falls in a loop reloading itself.

Comment: Are you submitting the form to the same page? If that is the case, the problem is that you are submitting the form every time the page loads so it will end up doing that over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I noticed that the page was trying to submit the form too quickly. First, I set a timer to 5 seconds after the form loaded and then call the click function of the submit button.
Then, I just used a window.unload function to be called when the entire DOM is created:

```js
window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById('submit-button').click(); };
```

And that is working fine. I hope this helps some other people.

Thanks!